# Format of External Links on Facebook

Tags: facebook, security, url, web, url-encoding

I have seen when you visit a profile on FB and click on link provided in

Contact Information --> Website

Facebook first take you to url format mentioned below

```
http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nwaonfire.com%2F&h=BAQByDCFo
```

and then takes you to the site .

My question is why  facebook does so, Iam asking because there is a place in my application where iam allowing users to enter website urls.

Answer (score 1):

...and the reason for facebook using the mentioned link instead of linking directly to http://www.nwaonfire.com is that facebook is evil.

They want to know which links are popular, where their users are going and where the link came from.

I also see a format as http://www.facebook.com/l/BAQByDCFo/www.nwaonfire.com where the BAQByDCFo is a hash value.

Answer (score 0):

URL encoding is done so that a second URL can be placed within the first's query string without breaking the original URL. For example, implying directory structure by using the "/" character or breaking out of name value pair by using "&". If you're going to be embedding a URL as a query string parameter, you must encode it first. How you do this will differ depending on the language you're working with but most web based frameworks have a native or library based function to easily do this.

Comment: what does this line mean "without breaking the original URL"

Comment: For example, a "/" is a reserved character in the URL spec: http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt It can't be used as part of the URL other than after the protocol (http) or to denote hierarchical structure. In your example, it's been escaped to "%3A" so it can be passed in the query string without is being an illegal use of the character.